# Performance wise, Which is better approach in grouping classes, structs, enums & etc

Tags: ios, swift, struct, enums

Which is better:

Option 1: Having them all (by type ex. Enums) on 1 file

**OR**

Option 2: Having 1 file per (by type: Ex. Enums)

Following are the example according to the options:

## Option 1

**Enums.swift**

```
enum Mood {
    case Happy
    case Sad
}

enum World {
    case Round
    case Flat
}
```

## Option 2

**Mood.swift**

```
enum Mood {
    case Happy
    case Sad
}
```

**World.swift**

```
enum World {
    case Round
    case Flat
}
```

Comment: This is not a performance issue; this is a question for how you structure your files so that you can find the definitions you are looking for.  Personally I would use option 2.

Comment: What @Paulw11 said. Also you could group similar enums in the same file, which would prevent the project from becoming too modular.

Comment: If we talk about compile time, placing everything in one file will increase compile speed. There's no difference in run time though so it's really up to your goals here.

Answer (score -1):

In a video, Uber guy says when they put all their models in a single file, build time decreased a lot.

video link: https://www.skilled.io/u/swiftsummit/swift-with-a-hundred-engineers

> Lastly, we started combining files, and we found out that combining all of our 200 models into one file decreased the compilation time from 1min35sec, to just 17sec. So we are like, "Hold on, this is interesting, combining everything into one makes it much faster." The reason for this is that, as much as I know, that a compiler does type checking for every single file. So if you spawn 200 processes of Swift compilers, it needs to 200x check all the other files and make sure that you're using the correct types. So combining everything into one makes it much faster.

Comment: In which video??

Comment: Why does your answer contain a screenshot of text? You can prefix a paragraph with `>` to indicate that it's a block quote.

Comment: Fixed post with video link and quote styling.